# Gulp.js HTML partials and loops

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I'm in the process of creating new web development workflow.

Currently I'm using Gulp to compile Sass files, compress CSS/JS/images and to view live website using BrowserSync.

I'm missing one page. Some simple and most important - super fast HTML templating engine. I'm aware of gulp-file-include. It's very fast but missing one crucial part - basic loops. I don't want to write 20 posts / 100 list elements etc.

I've tried using Haml with Gulp but compiling process was a little too long.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not exactly sure what you're looking for.

But I guess [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) might be the right thing. You can use iterations, for example:

```
- var n = 0
ul
  while n < 4
   li= n++
```

Will output you this

```
  <ul>
     <li>0</li>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
 </ul>
```

Or you can use emmet for your editor of choice. So you can make something like this

```
ul.foo>li*5
```

To create a list with the class foo and 5 list items. There are even more complex expressions possible.

Comment: Oh, this is so great. Fast and also syntax looks very clean. Thank you so much.